# GGplot histogram cutting off first values unless zoomed in

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have some data that I cannot make a repro of: 1 line = Customer, year, quantity ordered. I need a histogram of these quantities split by year:

```
ggplot(cust.year %>%
               mutate(yearly.cases = ceiling(yearly.cases)), aes(x = yearly.cases)) +
        geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, fill = "black") +
        xlab("Yearly Cases") +
        facet_wrap("year")
```

The plots output shows the data like this:
[image: plots pane]

I noticed some low values seem to be me missing, and when I click zoom they show up:
[image: zoomed plots]

They show up in shiny and save as the version missing bars, what's up with this? I've tried adjusting xlim to no avail.

EDIT: A more extreme example...
[image]

Comment: Would you mind making your issue reproducible? E.g. I used `set.seed(42); cust.year <- data.frame(year = sample(c(2018, 2019), 10000, replace = TRUE), yearly.cases = exp(rnorm(10000)))`but wasn't able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: This is likely due to `geom_histogram()` drawing filled rectangles of sub-pixel widths. If you set `geom_histogram(colour = {...})` the rectangles acquire lines, which have an absolute width that should be visible upon resizing the plot.

Comment: Unrelated to the graphical glitch or your question, I find in similar cases that a log-transformation of the x-axis helps focussing on the distribution instead of the outliers that now occupy +/- 80% of your axis range.

Comment: @teunbrand changing fill to colour fixed the issue of bars getting cut out of the graphical output in shiny. Good enough for me!

Comment: You can both set the colour and the fill, just to be sure